# How to hide class on print

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a page in that page the user can drag and drop elements into a container but I don't have any restriction so user can drag element outside the container. I'm thinking about adding borders to the container but I have to print this page but I don't want to print the borders. This is what I have:

```
.bordes {
        border: solid;
        border-color: #ff0000;
    }

@media print {
        .bordes {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
```

But this hide all the elements inside the div with this class and I only want to hide the borders, here is the code example:

[Code here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALBaWy)

If you see the example, all its fine but when you click on the print button all the div is hidden and I only want to hide the red borders. Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, you want to hide the borders when printing?  if so instead of `display:none`, use `border:none`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the border only:

```
@media print {
        .bordes {
            border: 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually I was playing with the code and I put border: none and that works jajaja, anyway thanks!

Comment: Nice Miguel! You are welcome! Keep in mind border: 0 stands for border width and border:none disables the style.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
display: none !important;
```

use,

```
border: none;
```

Comment: No need for !important though

Comment: @GeorgiosDimitriadis answer updated..thankyou for the valid suggestion..